# Link to a PDF file globally accessible from outside Salesforce

Tags: force.com-sites, pdf, custom-link

We want to create a link to a pdf file which is accessible from outside Salesforce. 
I have found following description but have no success when trying to follow these steps:

> 1. Save your document in a static resource.
>
>    2. Write click on the "View file" link and copy the link location from the attached Static Resource Detail page.
>    3. Create a Public Site if you do not have already.
>    4. Create a public link using copied link location and Website URL.
>    5. Website Site URL/Paste your copied link location, the link should be look like this
>         http://vk-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/resource/1303802742000/TestPDF

source: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008pAqIAI

The points are a bit unclear to me...
And is this still the way to go?
Especially point 4. is unclear to me

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I have tested this and worked as expected with proper URL:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Resource.PDFDemo01)}" > PDF Link </apex:outputLink>
```

Also successfully accessed it from other HTML:

```
<a href='http://abs01tp01-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/PublicSiteDemo01/resource/1492074880000/PDFDemo01'>Click for PDF</a>
```

I hope this may help you